# Why do we have to lift state in the tic-tac-toe tutorial?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the official react [tic-tac-toe tutorial](https://react.dev/learn/tutorial-tic-tac-toe), the second part implements a history of moves. For this it creates a new Game component and lifts the state from the Board to Game. I don't understand why we have to lift state from the Board to Game. We can also implement history of moves by creating the history state directly in the Board component.

The tutorial provides an explanation:

> Placing the history state into the Game component will let you remove the squares state from its child Board component. Just like you “lifted state up” from the Square component into the Board component, you will now lift it up from the Board into the top-level Game component. This gives the Game component full control over the Board’s data and lets it instruct the Board to render previous turns from the history.

However, we can also render previous history by implementing it in the Board component. Then why do we have to lift state from Board to Game?

Comment: `This gives the Game component full control over the Board’s data and lets it instruct the Board to render previous turns from the history.` i.e. the Game controls history, not the Board

Comment: So its a design decision for segregating responsibility. In this case, board component is responsible for rendering the squares where as the game component is responsible for maintaining history and controlling what the board should render?

Comment: I haven't read the tutorial, I imagine the "design decision" is explained in there

Answer (score 0):

We have to lift the 'history' state up because we want to display the list of past moves outside the Board component. It is reasonable because the Board component should only be responsible for managing the 9 squares and displaying the status, which includes showing the next player and winner.

We need 'history' state to display the list of past moves. So it is essential to lift the state outside the Board component so that we can display the list of past moves outside the Board component.

We could have proceeded without lifting the state up by displaying the list inside the Board component, but that will result in unsegregated logics and makes the code less readable.